# Is there any way to prevent react-select (Select.Async) from deleting the search input value on unfocus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

**Situation:** 

I have one normal select(categories), which determines what Options are loaded for the Select.Async from react-select.
**Problem:** 

Lets say someone searches for an option in Select.Async, while `category A` is selected. Then he realizes, that the option he is searching for is only available in `category B`. So he switches category in the first select. But while he clicks out of the search box from Select.Async, the input he made vanishes and he has to type it again.

Is there something I can do to keep his input even if I update the set of options while the search input is not in focus?

```
<select id="categories">
    <option value="1" selected>A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>

<Select.Async loadOptions={load} />
```

[Complete code-sample](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KrBJnRLI1yGIWfQTnqk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it out:

the property `value` of Select.Async is not the actual value of the input field. If you want to set the `value` of the input, there is a prop called inputRenderer. There you define an input within a div with all predefined `inputProps` (simply write `<input {...inputProps}`) and handle the value on your own.

```
render(){
    var inputChange = (input) => this.setState({value: input});
    var renderInput = (inputProps) => {
        if(this.state.value == ''){
            this.state.placeholder = 'Select ...';
        } else {
            this.state.placeholder = '';
        }
        var setCurserPosAtEnd = (event) => {
            if(event.target)
                event.target.setSelectionRange(event.target.value.length, event.target.value.length);
        }
        return (
            <div className='Select-input'>
                <input {...inputProps} value={this.state.value} onFocus={setCurserPosAtEnd} />
            </div>
        );
    }
    return(
        ...
        <Select.Async 
            loadOptions={loadOptionHandler} 
            onBlurResetsInput={false} 
            onCloseResetsInput={false} 
            inputRenderer={renderInput} 
            placeholder={this.state.placeholder} 
            onInputChange={inputChange} />
        ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the prop you are looking after:

```
<Select.Async loadOptions={load} onBlurResetsInput={false}/>
```

More options [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#further-options)

The full working [example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KrBXsheELN4KnvqFflc):

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {

  constructor()
  {
     super();
     this.state = {value: ""};  
  }

  render(){
    var load = (input, callback) => this.load(input, callback);
    return (
      <div class="container">
        <select id="select">
          <option value="1" selected>A</option>
          <option value="2">B</option>
          <option value="3">C</option>
        </select>

        <Select.Async 
          value={this.state.value}
          onBlurResetsInput={false}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            this.setState({value: newValue});
          }}           
          loadOptions={load} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  load(input, callback){
    var select = document.getElementById("select");
    var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(selected);
    var options = [];
    switch(selected){
      case "1":
        options = [{label: "A", value: 1}, {label: "B", value: 2}, {label: "C", value: 3}];
        break;
      case "2":
        options = [{label: "D", value: 4}, {label: "E", value: 5}, {label: "F", value: 6}];
        break;
      case "3":
        options = [{label: "G", value: 7}, {label: "H", value: 8}, {label: "I", value: 9}];
        break;
    }

    callback(null, {
      options: options
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: works when Select.Async gets out of focus. But when I select another option in the select above, the input gets deleted. Is there a way to set the input programmatically?

Comment: I am afraid that there is no such possibility as for now.

Comment: this example only seems to work because when I change the value in the normal select, react does no re-render because the state did not change. But if it forces a re-render your example code does not work. Found the solution while scouring the source code of react-select. Added answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use **`inputValue`** prop.

Basically we modify the related state variable inside onInputChangeHandler and onMenuCloseHandler event handlers.

E.x.

```
const Bar = React.memo((props: PropsWithChildren<any>) => {
    const searchRef = useRef<any>();

    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<any>('');

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            searchRef.current.focus();
        });
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.lastSelectedOption)
            setInputValue(props.lastSelectedOption.value);
    }, [props.lastSelectedOption]);

    const onSearchChangeHandler = async (event) => {
        //...
    });

    const onInputChangeHandler = (inputValue, { action }) => {
        setInputValue(inputValue);

        if (action == 'input-change' && !inputValue) props.setLastSelectedOption(null);
    }

    const onKeyDownHandler = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            searchRef.current.focus();
        });
    };

    const onMenuCloseHandler = () => setInputValue(inputValue);

    return (
        <div className="d-inline-flex w-100">
            <AsyncSelect
                className="rounded-pill flex-grow-1"
                placeholder="Search.."
                ref={searchRef}
                inputValue={inputValue}
                value={props.lastSelectedOption}
                onChange={onChangeHandler}
                onInputChange={onInputChangeHandler}
                onKeyDown={onKeyDownHandler}
                onMenuClose={onMenuCloseHandler}
            />
        </div>
    )
})
```

In the code above, prop lastSelectedOption is an object like this

```
{
    value: event.value,
    label: event.label
}
```